# I can not get ipython notebook working. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed ipython notebook using their instructions. That didn't work. So i tried other instructions. I seemed to get closer to getting it working. currently this is the output i get when i try to run ipnotebook.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==1.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 544, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 312, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 362, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 307, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 474, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 405, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 38, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

Comment: the error just says you have not installed `jinja2`; do `apt-cache search jinja` and install the package

Comment: Wow, i feel stupid. When i read that i figured that came with the ipython install. Thank you so much. it worked.

Comment: While this probably is a duplicate, the question that this is a duplicate of does not include Eric's answer about installing using your package manager (which actually pointed me to fixing this on a non-Ubuntu linux by same method). I'll add a comment there too.

Answer (score 3):

In order to load Jinja locally you also have to have it installed locally

```
easy_install Jinja2
```

or

```
pip install Jinja2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-jinja2
```